# Transform getArgs from IO [String] to IO [Int]

Tags: haskell, monads

I'd like to write a program like the following:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add a b = a + b

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getIntArgs
    case args of
        [a,b] -> putStrLn $ show $ add a b
```

Is there a way I can write the function `getIntArgs` in terms of `getArgs` (from `System.Environment`)?

Comment: `(fmap . fmap) read $ getArgs :: IO [Int]`

Comment: (note that `print` is `putStrLn . show`)

Comment: It's not actually the function that gets Int arguments you want, but you'd like arguments and you'd like to interpret them as ints, right?  Does considering it as two separate steps help you?  Get args, convert strings to ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unwrap it in your head first. You need a function that goes from `IO [String] -> IO [Int]`. First consider a function that goes from `f a -> f b` -- well that's `fmap`!

Then we just have to find a function that goes from `a -> b`. In this case `a ~ [String]` and `b ~ [Int]`. Now we see another functor wrapping our concrete types -- `fmap` works again, this time abstracting away the `[]` instead of `IO`.

Now we need a function that goes `String -> Int`. This is `read`.

```
getIntArgs = fmap (fmap read) getArgs
```

since `f (g x) = (f . g) x`, we can write (and should prefer, it's Haskelly-er): `(fmap . fmap) read $ getArgs`.

In fact your whole function is just:

```
main :: IO ()
main = (fmap (sum . fmap read) getArgs) >>= print
-- assuming you're okay replacing `(+)` with `sum`

-- if not:
main = (fmap (uncurry (+) . listToTuple . fmap read) getArgs) >>= print
  where
  listToTuple [a, b] = (a, b)
```